# How to defined type by value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Code:

```
type InputProps = {
  a: string;
};

type SelectProps = {
  b: string;
};

type TypeProps = 'Input' | 'Select';

type ConfigProps = {
  type: TypeProps;
  componentProps: InputProps | SelectProps;
};

const config: ConfigProps = {
  type: 'Input',
  componentProps: { 
    a: 'demo'
  }
};
```

How to defined `ConfigProps`, if `type` prop value equal `Input` then `componentProps` should be      `InputProps`.

Expect:

```
const config: ConfigProps = {
  type: 'Input',
  componentProps: { 
    b: 'demo' // ERROR, because type equal to 'Input', but InputProps just allow prop a
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your type to be more explicit on the values:

```
type ConfigProps = {
  type: 'Input';
  componentProps: InputProps;
} | {
   type: 'Select';
   componentProps: SelectProps;
};
```

this way if `type` is `'Input'` then `componentProps` must be `InputProps`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add one extra layer, as you can see by adding the `InputConfigProps` and `SelectConfigProps` types. By setting ConfigType to either of these it is only possible to implicitly infer one of the two.

```
type InputProps = {
  a: string;
};

type SelectProps = {
  b: string;
};

type Temp = {
    Input: InputProps,
    Select: SelectProps
}

type InputConfigProps = {
    type: "Input",
    componentProps: InputProps;
}

type SelectConfigProps = {
  type: "Select";
  componentProps: SelectProps;
};

type ConfigProps = InputConfigProps | SelectConfigProps;

const config: ConfigProps = {
    type: "Input",
    componentProps: {
        a: "demo",
    },
};
```